# How to get Android world clock cities

Tags: android, timezone, clock, alarm

Hhow to get world clock cities like below screen.

[image]

Thanx all

Comment: what does it have to do with android, clock or alarm?

Comment: because alarm, clock and timezone all in one place

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do with it afterwards but this is how you could get that data:

use [Google Places API Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete?hl=de) to search for places, then send that string to
[Google Places API Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=de) to get the longitude and latitude data, this is what you send to [The Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

Im sure this goes all in one somehow but what i want to show is google API's are the way to go.

cheers!